# Trying to understand composition between c++ classes

Tags: c++, class, constructor, composition

I am having a hard time getting my head around how to correctly perform composition between C++ classes. Here is an example of where I'm getting stuck:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Super
{
private:
    int idNum;
    string Name;
public:
    Super(int, string);
    void setSuper();
};

Super::Super(const int id, const string superName)
{
    idNum = id;
    Name = superName;
}

class Sidekick
{
private:
    int sideIdNum;
    string sideName;
    Super hero;
public:
    Sidekick(int, string, Super);
    void setSidekick();
};

int main()
{
    Super sm;
    Sidekick sk;

    sm.setSuper();
    sk.setSidekick();

    return 0;
}

void Super::setSuper()
{
    int superID;
    string sname;

    cin >> superID;
    cin >> sname;

    Super(superID, sname);
}

void Sidekick::setSidekick()
{
    int id;
    string siName;
    Super man;

    cin >> id;
    cin >> siName;
    //How do I perform action that automatically obtains the attributes 
    //from the object "hero" from Super?
}
```

Comment: where did you get stuck? what are the questions?

Comment: You can't call the constructor like that to reset the object if that's what you're trying to do in there.

Comment: @taocp Updated with question, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attributes from Super class, you need to provide getter helpers. Below is an example:

```
using namespace std;

class Super
{
private:
    int idNum;
    string Name;
public:
    Super(int, string);
    void setSuper();
    int getId() {return idNum;}   // added here
    string getName() {return Name;} // added here
};

...

void Sidekick::setSidekick()
{
    int id;
    string siName;
    Super man;

    cin >> id;
    cin >> siName;
    //How do I perform action that automatically obtains the attributes 
    //from the object "hero" from Super?

    // Use yours helper here
    cout << hero.getId();
    cout << hero.getName();
}
```

By the way, you cannot calls constructors like you do before. You have, at least, two choices, either you setup the attributes at your object creation, or you provide setter helpers to perform this action.

Comment: I have been trying to understand this for 3 days now. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, but I was looking into your code more carefully and I noticed that you call setSuper() to initialize your attributes. Just strip out the constructor Super(superID, sname). It is incorrect to call that way, as I said before, and totally unecessary here, once you have direct access to your attributes. Just do idNum = superID and Name = sname